# How to handle NULL values in WHERE clause and change target column based upon its encounter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the WHERE clause to change what column it is evaluating when NULL is encountered. For instance I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
WHERE CASE WHEN c.cust_id_1(@variable) IS NOT NULL THEN c.cust_id_1 = @variable
         ELSE CASE WHEN c.cust_id_2(@variable) IS NOT NULL THEN c.cust_id_2 = @variable
              ELSE c.cust_id_3 = @variable
```

Is something like this possible? One of the 3 cust_id's will not be NULL.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for asking, I'm not at work right now, but tomorrow morning I will give both you and the other gentleman's answers a try! They both look super promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems like less than optimal table design, but isn't a simple `COALESCE` where you're after?

```
WHERE @variable = COALESCE(cust_id_1, cust_id_2, cust_id_3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `CASE` expression for this, you just need logical operators

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
WHERE
(c.cust_id_1 IS NOT NULL AND c.cust_id_1 = @variable)
OR
(c.cust_id_2 IS NOT NULL AND c.cust_id_2 = @variable)
OR
(c.cust_id_3 IS NOT NULL AND c.cust_id_3 = @variable)
```